# Source code for THINC API test application?

Tags: api, okuma

Every machine with the THINC API installed comes with a test program to test all of the API functionality (by default, located in Programs -> Okuma -> THINC-API -> THINC _ Test App) where _ is the machine type. This is useful, but the source code would be even more useful. Is it available anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the API installed, look in `D:\Program files\Okuma\THINC API\ThincMC`

If the test project isn't there, post back and I'll help you find it.

Comment: Found it on my Lathe, thanks.    `D:\Program Files\Okuma\THINC API\ThincLathe\thincLathe.sln`