# Network File Transfer of Part Programs and Part Progam Select

Tags: c#, .net, okuma

We are developing a project to send G Code programs from a server to an OKUMA CNC. We will need to do a Program Select on the OKUMA CNC for these files.

I couldn't find an example of this. Kindly help me.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the problem yourself first?

Comment: Daniel, sorry me this is my first question. we will start to develop this project and i cant find proper way on thinc api examples about this issue. thats way i asked you to find the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source code for THINC API test application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18770520/2596334)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File Transfer can be accomplished any number of ways.
Typically people will enable Windows File Sharing and use the System.IO classes for automation.

- See [How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders - C# Programming Guide | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders)

And example of how to perform Part Program Select can be found in the example program's "Program" tab with the Button labeled "Select Program". Looking at the THINC API 1.21.1.0 Lathe Sample Application, this leads you to Line 18495 in the frmMain.vb file.

```
Private Sub progSelectProgramButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles progSelectProgramButton.Click
    Try
        m_objCMDProgram.SelectMainProgram(prog1.Text, prog2.Text, prog3.Text, prog4.Text)
    Catch ae As ApplicationException
        DisplayError("CMD program", ae.Message)
        'Exit Sub
    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayError("CMD Program", ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Please find additional information in the API Help file under the **Command API - CProgram** class.

[image: CProgram.SelectMainProgram]